# Some Tkinter functions not available when using different computer

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

The following code runs fine, but is reporting an unresolved reference in Pycharm. This code doesn't report any unresolved references on my other machine. I have run 'invalidate caches' in Pycharm, and I have re-installed everything to no avail. This is also occuring on other function calls such as tk.Grid.conlumnconfigure, tk.Grid.rowconfigure etc.

I'm using Python 3.10 and pycharm 2021.3.1

```
# Create the Menu Bar
    self.main_menu = tk.Menu(master)
    master.config(menu=self.main_menu)
    self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.main_menu, tearoff=False)
    self.main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Open...", command=self.open)
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.save)
    self.file_menu.add_command(label="Save As...", command=self.save_as)
```

i get the following error on master.config:

```
Cannot find reference 'config' in 'Misc | None'
ignore an unresolved reference 'tkinter.Misc.config'
```

Edit: Here's a full minimal example. "columnconfigure" throws the same error:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        Button(self.master, text="test").grid(row=0, column=0)
        Grid.columnconfigure(self.master, 0, weight=1)



# initialize tkinter
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)

# set window title
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")

# show window
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: When in doubt, *always* test a script by saving it as a file and running it from a shell/cmd.exe. If that works, the error is somewhere in the IDE. In general, tkinter programs are not a good mix with interactive interpreters like IPython (and presumably pycharm).

Comment: @Matiiss Example added above

Comment: @RolandSmith I agree. This is a Pycharm issue, as the code executes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is PyCharm. To be precise, the problem is with the version.

The solution to your question is to install an older version. The version you use was released on `December 01 2021` from JetBrains.

You need a version earlier than `2021.3.1`. Try version `2021.2.3` which was released on `July 28 2021` from JetBrains.

In this way all the functions of Tkinter will be available

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure PyCharm is using the correct interpreter with the same version of Python? You can check this by going to Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter. I have run into many issues in the past because I did not realize that PyCharm had defaulted to an interpreter with Python 2.7.

Comment: if it was Python 2.7, it wouldn't raise that exception, it would raise an `ImportError` because it wouldn't be able to find module `tkinter` because in Python 2.x it was named `Tkinter`

Comment: @Matiiss That is correct. My interpreter is confirmed to the Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue was with PyCharm 2021.3.1

I downgraded to 2021.2.3 and everything works now.